# Loop through elements with jquery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a list of items identified by classes and data- custom attributes as follows:

```
<div class="matrix_type" id="12" data-matrix-value="7"></div>
<div class="matrix_type" id="189" data-matrix-value="4"></div>
<div class="matrix_type" id="12090" data-matrix-value="10"></div>
<div class="matrix_type" id="1234" data-matrix-value="2"></div>
```

I want to use a button to trigger an AJAX post `<button id"send_matrix">Send<button>`

Once the button is clicked, I want to get associate each "div"  with its value in an object I can send in AJAX request with other data.

Any guides?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get all the div's and iterate through getting all the values before posting them in 'one' object, do the following:

```
$('#send_matrix').click(function(){

    // We post this to the server
    var postObject = {};

    //Get all the divs with the class of 'matrix_type' and iterate through
    $('.matrix_type').each(function(){

        //Get the id of the current div (please make them unique!)
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        //Get the matrix value of the current div
        var matrixValue = $(this).data('matrix-value');

        //Add a new key-value pair to the postObject
        postObject[id] = matrixValue;
    });


    //Replace this with the url you post the data to
    var url = 'www.something.com' 

    //Post the data to the server
    $.post(url, postObject, function(data, status){

            //Show the result of the attempted post (success or failure)
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```